# How to add dash or dashed border in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am tring to add a dashed border in one side,

```
{
  height: '100%',
  width: 20,
  position: 'absolute',
  borderRadius : 1,
  borderStyle: 'dashed',
  borderRightWidth: 1,
  borderRightColor: 'rgba(161,155,183,1)'
}
```

This doesn't work, but when I change this to

```
{
  height: '100%',
  width: 20,
  position: 'absolute',
  borderRadius : 1,
  borderStyle: 'dashed',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'rgba(161,155,183,1)'
}
```

Works but border in 4 side.
How do I add bashed border just in one side?
Also is there a way to add more spacing to the dash?
`"react-native": "0.57.7"`

Comment: can u change dashed to dotted

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7838

Based upon looking at the code this looks like a intentional limitation. There is code that specifically checks to see if both the color and width are the same on all sides if trying to use a dashed or dotted border. I would venture to guess that if you were to set borderWidth to 1 instead of just borderBottomWidth that the warning will go away and your border will show.

You can achieve this by using this kind of mask:

```
const inputStyles = 
StyleSheet.create({
container: {
height: 20,
marginRight: 25,
marginLeft: 25,
paddingTop: 25,
paddingBottom: 25,
borderStyle: 'dotted',
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: '#b7c2c6',
position: 'relative',
overflow: 'hidden',
},
topMask: {
height: 3,
width: 9999,
backgroundColor: 'white',
position: 'absolute',
top: -3,
left: 0,
},
rightMask: {
height: 9999,
width: 3,
backgroundColor: 'white',
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
right: -3,
},
leftMask: {
height: 9999,
width: 3,
backgroundColor: 'white',
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
left: -3,
},
});
```

This issue have not been solved yet:https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17251

You can set `borderRadius` to 1 or 0.5 to get dashed border.

Comment: The issue you're posting is old and resolved almost a year ago by Facebook.

Comment: Well, I did add a `borderRadius: 1` looking at that issue in my code (added in my question). Still not sure why that didn't work. :(

Comment: You cannot get one side dashed border in react native yet. You may try [this](https://js.coach/react-native-dash?search=dash&collection=React+Native) for now.

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, you guys are amazing. Though I am using react-native, it doesn't use px/em. I got the idea. Also I did thought of this idea. and thats the workaround I did a while back, the only issue with this approach is the border width became too thick. also the gap between the dash became lesser. So I decided to fix it with [react-native-dash](https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-dash)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's just for pasting but you have a lot of syntax errors in what you posted

it should be:

```
{
  height: '100%',
  -width: 20, - width: 1px/em/
  position: 'absolute',
  -borderRadius : 1-, borderRaduis : 1px/em/... or any other size
  borderStyle: 'dashed',
  -borderWidth: 1-, borderWidth: 1px/em/...
  borderColor: 'rgba(161,155,183,1)'
}
```

changing only one border and not the whole div is simple as stating it 
`borderBottomStyle: 'dashed'` or `borderTopStyle`,`borderRightStyle`,`borderLeftStyle`

Comment: Did not know about that. I will give a try to it tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, this is accurate just use CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much, you guys are amazing. Though I am using react-native, it doesn't use px/em. I got the idea. Also I did thought of this idea.
and thats the workaround I did a while back, the only issue with this approach is the border width became too thick. also the gap between the dash became lesser.
So I decided to fix it with https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-dash

Comment: The question is about `react-native` not css

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099